# What's wrong with that proof?

Tags: fake-proofs

What wrong with this proof?

$(-1)=(-1)^{\frac{2}{2}}=(-1)^{2\times \frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{1}=1$ then $1=-1$

Comment: The issue is how you define $x \mapsto (x)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is a multiple-valued "function", since in general $x$ has two square roots. One could also write:

$$\sqrt1=-1$$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

it is fake
suppose f(x)=x
and
g(x)=(x)^(2/2)

f(x) is not equal to g(x)
domain of both is R
but g(x)=|x| instead of f(x)=x

Answer (score 0):

$(-1)^{2 \times\frac{1}{2}}$ is not equal to $\sqrt{1}$.  The correct way to simplify $(-1)^{2 \times\frac{1}{2}}$, using universally accepted orders of operation (because they work), is to start by simplifying the exponent ${2 \times\frac{1}{2}}$ to $1$.  Then you get $(-1)^1$ , which is equal to $-1$, which is where you started.